# How to create a new column if some value match from a list (something like get dummies)

Tags: python, pandas

I have a df like:

```
text
hello how are you
hello people
hello stackoverflow
```

and a list like this:

words = ["Hello","people", "stackoverflow"]

Expected output:

```
text                  Hello         people          stackoverflow
hello how are you       1             0                  0
hello people            1             1                  0
hello stackoverflow     1             0                  1
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [`Series.str.get_dummies`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.get_dummies.html) with [`DataFrame.reindex`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reindex.html) for filter columns by list (vallues has to be lowercase for match) and last [`DataFrame.join`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.join.html) to original:

```
words = ["hello","people", "stackoverflow"]
df1 = df.join(df['text'].str.get_dummies(' ').reindex(columns=words))

print (df1)
                  text  hello  people  stackoverflow
0    hello how are you      1       0              0
1         hello people      1       1              0
2  hello stackoverflow      1       0              1
```